# Passing php variable as parameter to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm trying to call a javascript function with one argument being a variable gotten from a drop box.  This script works fine if only passed the value from the current drop box using "this.value", however when trying to pass the variable the code doesn't work.  The variable is properly being populated from the value in the drop box when I use echo statements. I think the problem is with actually passing the variable to the javascript function.  The function showSection(q, r) is never being called as the write statement is never executing.  Any help would be appreciated.  Here is my php and javascript code

```
echo "<select name=\"course\" onchange=\"showSection($q, this.value)\">";
```

Comment: a wall of code isn't that nice of a greeting.

Comment: This PHP code is just pleading to be MySQL injected.

Comment: This is the question.  what is the syntax for passing the variable to the function,  whichever way I try to pass the variable to the function it doesn't work.  It only works when I pass one variable using this.value not a stored variable

Comment: try to examine the resulting markup in the browser and see if it is correct. in addition, check the HTTP traffic and see if the server returns the correct response.

Comment: The first two drop boxes are coming up, the function that calls the third file is never being called because of a problem with the passed parameters

Comment: give a sample output of `echo $q;` too

Comment: when i echo $q it prints out the correctly selected option from the drop box

Comment: "write statement" Do you have a document.write in the showSection? That is a NONO. Can you show that function?

Comment: You don't actually pass a variable to JavaScript.  You simply output JavaScript, and the browser treats it as if it was hard-coded.  If that much is working, then this has nothing to do with PHP, and you should be showing us the output of your PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If the $q or this.value are string values, you have to pass it within quotes.

```
echo "<select name='course' onchange='showSection(\"$q\", \"this.value\")'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure inserting the value of `$q` doesn't produce javascript syntax errors. The reasonable way to do that is to use [`json_encode`](http://us.php.net/json_encode) on the value.

After that you need to make sure both single and double quotes are escaped in that value, to keep the html correct. [`htmlspecialchars`](http://us.php.net/htmlspecialchars) is used for that. In my opinion, converting both single and double quotes always (`ENT_QUOTES`) is the best choice.

And the end result is (I'm using heredoc syntax here, because I find it more readable):

```
$escaped = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($q), ENT_QUOTES);
echo <<<HTML
<select name="course" onchange="showSection($escaped, this.value);">
HTML;
```